# total solutions(recursive func)

Tags: python, recursion

I have this recursive function which is search possible solutions for Climbing Stairs problem.
Is it posible to return final count without global variable?

```
def foo(number, steps):
    global count
    if steps == number:
        count += 1
    else:
        if number - 2 >= steps:
            foo(number, steps+2)
        if number -1 >= steps:
            foo(number, steps+1)
    return count
```

Comment: `global` keyword is not necessary

Comment: remove the `global` statement; this variable is local to your function.  `return count` is enough.  Your main program will do something such as `print(foo(12, 0))`

Comment: It's necessary if the global `count` is how the count is passed from one call to the next.

Comment: @chepner Then `def foo(number, steps, count=0)` would be preferable.

Comment: You're all over-complicating this, honestly. (It helps to realize that the problem is a thinly veiled version of calculating the Fibonacci sequence.)

Comment: @Guimoute Do you check your solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the idea in these kinds of recursive algorithms is to *use* the return value from the recursive calls, in the current call.

In this particular case: the number of ways to get to the top from the current position, is the *sum of* the ways that start with a single step, and the ways that start with a double step.

We can also simplify the logic by addition additional base cases for the situation where we have overstepped the goal, and reporting that there are no solutions in this case. That means we don't need a separate check before each recursive call, and it also handles cases where we were asked to *start* beyond the goal.

Finally, we do not need separate tracking for the number of steps taken and the total distance to the goal: all we care about is the *remaining distance*.

So:

```
def number_of_paths(distance):
    if distance < 0:
        # We overstepped the goal, so now we can't get there.
        return 0
    elif distance == 0:
        # We're there, so there's exactly one way to get there: wait in place.
        return 1
    else:
        # We try both possible step sizes and total the results.
        return number_of_paths(distance - 2) + number_of_paths(distance - 1)
```